# Mulitplicity one property for $\mathcal{D}'$ and $L^2$ over a homogeneous space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ and $G_0$ be Lie groups, and suppose that a homogeneous space $X=G/G_0$ have a $G$-invariant measure.
It is known (E.G.F. Thomas [showed](//www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304020808714828)) that there is an admissible parametrization $\{\mathcal{H}_s\}_{s\in S}$ of the irreducible invariant Hilbert subspaces in $\mathcal{D}'(X)$, by which any invariant irreducible Hilbert subspace $\mathcal{H}$ is represented as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}=\int_S^\oplus \mathcal{H}_s\,dm(s).
\end{equation}
The [result](//zbmath.org/1112.43008) can be considerd as a variant of the above result.

Question:
It is known that if $L^2(X)$ is multiplicity-one, that is, there exists a unique Radon measure $m$ on the set $S$ such that
\begin{equation}
L^2(X)=\int_S^\oplus \mathcal{H}_s\,dm(s),
\end{equation}
then any invariatn Hilbert subspace in $\mathcal{D}'(X)$ is multiplicity-one.
I think there is no proof and I can not imagine it.
Is there a related fact? It is helpful to shere.

I am not sure, but it may be restated that if $(G,G_0)$ is a Gelfand pair, that is, $\mathrm{Hom}_{G_0}(\pi,\mathbb{C})\leq 1$ for all irreducible unitary representation $\pi$of $G$, then $(G,G_0)$ is a generalized Gelfand pair, that is, $\mathrm{Hom}_{G_0}(\pi^{-\infty},\mathbb{C})\leq 1$ for all irreducible unitary representation $\pi$ of $G$.